# Credentials expired using AWS TVM on Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using some of the code from the UserPreferenceDemo, the sample AWS Android SDK app. I have the sample app working so that it is able to create a new DynamoDB table. However, when I try to implement the same code in my app, I get the log message "Credentials were expired" in the AmazonClientManager class and my app crashes.

Here is the code I use to create the table.

```
final Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubmitComplete)
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i(TAG, "submitBttn clicked.");

        new DynamoDBManagerTask()
        .execute(DynamoDBManagerType.CREATE_TABLE);
    }
});
```

And here is the code that logs the message.

```
public Response validateCredentials() {

    Response ableToGetToken = Response.SUCCESSFUL;

    if (AmazonSharedPreferencesWrapper
            .areCredentialsExpired(this.sharedPreferences)) {

        synchronized (this) {

            if (AmazonSharedPreferencesWrapper
                    .areCredentialsExpired(this.sharedPreferences)) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Credentials were expired.");

                AmazonTVMClient tvm = new AmazonTVMClient( this.sharedPreferences, PropertyLoader.getInstance().getTokenVendingMachineURL(), PropertyLoader.getInstance().useSSL() );

                ableToGetToken = tvm.anonymousRegister();

                if (ableToGetToken.requestWasSuccessful()) {

                    ableToGetToken = tvm.getToken();

                    if (ableToGetToken.requestWasSuccessful()) {
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Creating New Credentials.");
                        initClients();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } else if (ddb == null) {

        synchronized (this) {

            if (ddb == null) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Creating New Credentials.");
                initClients();
            }
        }
    }

    return ableToGetToken;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple fix, stupid issue, but I was banging my head into this for a while.

Uninstalled and reinstalled the app. Now it works

Comment: I am using the latest CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider but that also expired my token...and your solution worked but do I need to do that again and again? what is the seen when I actually post my app on app store